# Type 'LodashReplace1x5' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, type-conversion, lodash

I have a weird problem using lodass/fp in typescript. it works but it shows error. i couldn't find-out why is this happening.

here is the error:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: string, currentValue: string, currentIndex: number, array: string[]) => string, initialValue: string): string', gave the following error.     Argument of type '(acc: string, curr: string) => fp.LodashReplace1x5' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: string, currentValue: string, currentIndex: number, array: string[]) => string'.       Type 'LodashReplace1x5' is not assignable to type 'string'.   Overload 2 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: string, currentValue: string, currentIndex: number, array: string[]) => string, initialValue: string): string', gave the following error.     Argument of type '(acc: string, curr: string) => fp.LodashReplace1x5' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: string, currentValue: string, currentIndex: number, array: string[]) => string'.       Type 'LodashReplace1x5' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

what is the problem? how should i fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it would detect the type, but it seems we have to tell the type explicitly as you can see in the below picture:

[image]